# "Travel Answers" - to be, or not to be?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

There's been some controversy over the site being called "Travel Answers", with people calling it boring or bland, and not standing out.

Look at, for example, [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) (the cooking.se site) - a punny, easy to remember name.

So, please add alternatives below, and we'll see if we can get some buy in on names.  Vote for either the current one(I'll add it) or others, or downvote if you don't like one or more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have been working on standardizing site names across the network and steadily moving away from [custom names and domains](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/).

Combined with the fact that "Travel Exchange" is [right out](https://www.travelexchange.net/) and "Travel Answers" is both dull and a result of some internal miscommunication on our part<sup>1</sup>... we're going to stick with "Travel Stack Exchange" as the official name of the site.

The logo will be updated soon to drop "Answers".

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I don't have a source for that, but trust me.</sub>

Comment: so does that mean that [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) will be getting renamed?

Comment: @MarkMayo No, we aren't planning to rename sites that have had custom names for, at this point, years. We are, however, planning to add something sort of a byline to emphasize that these sites are a part of the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I'm really not happy about this name. How should I explain other people what a travel stack exchange is? Probably, they will assume that it is related to trading travel stocks or something like this.

Comment: @AnnaLear - any progress on this?

Comment: @MarkMayo I pinged Jin to remind him and ask him to bump this up on his todo list.

Comment: The twitter name for this site is "StackTravel". To me that seems catchy ("Hey man you can ask that on Stack Travel"), generalisable ("Stack Cooking", "Stack Graphics", "Stack Judaism", "Stack Wordpress"...), and just better. It's unique and SEO friendly, it's less confusing, less of a mouthful and catchier than "X Stack Exchange". It also sits nicely alongside "Stack Exchange" as the hub of "Stack" sites, and for people familiar with Stack Overflow, it makes the link to that site and difference from that site instantly 100% clear. Seems better to me.

Comment: @AnnaLear? :/  I figure I can ping you a year later to see ;)

Comment: Soon, @MarkMayo , soon :)

Comment: @AnnaLear: So we're now at 18 months and counting... for what value of `soon` can we expect the logo change? :)

Comment: @Flimzy Well, now it's just *extra* embarrassing. I'll ping ... someone.

Answer (score 10):

> Travel Exchange

Simple. Minimalistic. Steers people back from the confusion about what "exchanging stacks" has to do with travel, while still staying very close to "Stack Exchange".

Everybody will know what we're about as soon as they see it. We're about exchanging questions and answers. The word "exchange" already sounds right in relation to the topic of travel due to things such as currency exchange, exchange students, etc.

Yeah yeah it's not witty or clever. That means there's nothing to dislike about it ... besides being dull. But it's not as dull as "Travel Answers" (no offence to whoever came up with that!)

As a bonus it's still two words of about equal length with a space to plop the logo between.

Comment: Sounds like I should go there to trade timeshares...

Comment: Definitely don't want to pluralise the 'Travel' and say that fast...

Comment: @MarkMayo: Remember Experts Exchange? In the olden days of SE, it was a common source of entertainment, calling it at one point "the hyphen site" or somesuch.

Comment: @mindcorrosive I do indeed, that and Therapist.com, among others with unfortunate alternative prononciations ;)

Comment: The only thing I worry about with this one is that some other company or site might be using something too close...?

Comment: Hmm - like [Travel Exchange](https://www.travelexchange.net/)?

Answer (score 10):

> Mark Mayo's

Some [suggestions from Hippietrail](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8047872#8047872):

> Ask Mark
>
> Mark's been there
>
> Mark Knows

Would make a great name for the site..

For the logo:

[image]

Comment: We need a third button to go with the ↑ and ↓ buttons... maybe ❤ (-:

Comment: @hippietrail was that a heart button? or an ass button?

Comment: I couldn't find a Unicode "funny" or "laughter" symbol so feel free to interpret as you wish.

Comment: lol, awesome :)

Answer (score 7):

I don't assume that this question still has any relevance, but I can't help it:

> There and Back Again
>   <sub>A Traveler's Q&A Site</sub>

Answer (score 5):

> Now Boarding

Recognizably travelly, without pertaining only to a single form of travel.

Comment: I like this one.

Answer (score 3):

The current name:

> Travel Answers

Comment: My opinion is that we shouldn't go for a vague phrase unless it does a VERY good job of describing what the site is about.

Comment: While "Travel" is minimalism, "Travel Answers" is just Dullsville.

Answer (score 3):

> **Next Stop**

The name of the cooking site like Mark pointed out, "Seasoned Advice", is so great I'm trying to use it as inspriration. It's clever without being too clever.

- **Next Stop** makes you think of travel by train or bus without being focussed on only hard-core backpackers.
- It suggests that the next thing you should do when figuring out your trip is to stop by our site.
- To me at least it sounds a little bit cute or fun.
- It's less likely to already be in use than

Answer (score 1):

> All Destinations

I'm sure I've seen this at train stations or something in some places around the world. For when only one ticket window or platform is open no matter where you're going, etc.

This means it's already a familiar phrase to travellers. The added nice bit is that we really do cover all destinations, from the mundane to the exotic.

Comment: Q&All Destinations?

Answer (score 0):

> Going Places
>
> Think Travel

Answer (score -1):

> Wanderlust Wisdom

(I'm partial to alliteration)

Comment: I love the word "wanderlust" but I don't think it pairs well with "wisdom" at all.

Comment: @hippietrail: Feel free to propose alternatives. The idea was to have a "Travel" and "answers" replaced with synonyms, or related terms. Couldn't find a suitable "w"-word besides "wisdom"

Comment: Yeah I proposed a handful. I'm just jotting my thoughts under each that I have thoughts about, and I encourage others to jot down their thoughts too. Words tell more than clicks about what it is we do or don't like about an idea.

Comment: I really like Wanderlust! It is exactly what this site is about, and it sounds also a little bit exotic and interesting. Would be great if we find a cool name with Wanderlust.

Comment: You and I think it's about this, but some people think it's about making your transfer at Newark (-; I guess in reality it's about both. Travel problems from the mundane to the exotic.

Comment: @hippietrail our area51 line was "for road warriors and seasoned travellers", to be fair...

Comment: @MarkMayo: Yeah I know (-:

Answer (score -1):

> Been There

We've been there, done/seen/bought that - that's why we can give you good advice.

Comment: +1 I would argue to change it in Been there?! To also include the Q&A scope of travel SE :)

Comment: @RoflcoptrException: We may expand this for the full tagline: "Go far? - We've Been There"

Comment: It makes it sound like we got nothing out of being yeah: "Yeah yeah been there done that so what".

Answer (score -1):

> **Travel**

Simple, to the point, and the reason we're all here.  Might be hard to balance with the logo tho...

Comment: I think there's other sites with just one word. The logo can go to the north, south, east, or west of the name/slogan (-:

Answer (score -2):

> The Travel Destination

(make it 30 chars...)

Comment: Not quite as boring as "Travel Answers".

Answer (score -2):

> Stack Station (or Stack Exchange Station)

Uses the network and avoids being flight-centric.

Answer (score -2):

> On The Road

Some obvious shortcomings: too literary, might be confused with something car-related.  But otherwise I like it.

Answer (score -3):

> Itchy Feet

- Pro: A well-known [travel idiom in English](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/itchy_feet), doesn't look as foreign (or as lusty) as Wanderlust.
- Con: Not to be confused with athletes' foot. (Sometimes associated with hostel showers...)

Comment: My first association was indeed with a nasty dermatological condition.

Answer (score -4):

> All the Way to Timbuktu (or some variant)

Comment: Why not Kalamazoo?

Comment: Because Timbuktu has that colonial adventure ring to it ;)

Answer (score -4):

> Off the Beaten Track Q&A

(hey, I'm just spitballing here)

Comment: Makes us sound like we only do alternative/independent travel.

Comment: @our area51 line was "for road warriors and seasoned travellers" to be fair...

Comment: I guess only Mad Max and a few chefs-at-large were the expected audience at that time (-;

Answer (score -4):

> Beyond Borders

(make it 30 chars...)

Comment: There's [a movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0294357) with the same name already.

Comment: Might sound overly international-focussed to some.

Answer (score -4):

> Ask Seasoned Travellers

(a variant on Seasoned Advice from the cooking.se site)

Answer (score -4):

> Arrivals and Departures

Obvious travel terms but somehow not too clichéd for a travel site as far as I know.

Answer (score -4):

> Tickets and Information (or Ticket and Information Desk)

Not too clever. "Information" is what Q&A sites are about but would be too generic on its own. With the addition of "Tickets" it sounds travelly without focussing on one form of travel

Answer (score -4):

> Departure Hall

The place where people double-check everything before leaving for new adventures

Answer (score -5):

> Backpackistan

(well... we're brainstorming, aren't we :))

Comment: I love it - but it makes it sound like questions about transferring in Newark are off topic d-:

Answer (score -5):

> Gate 67

(the gate from the movie "The Terminal")

Comment: Looks like we're copying "Seat 61".

Answer (score -5):

> Tickets Please

Just another travel catchphrase that might not already be in use for the name of a travel site.

Answer (score -6):

> 500 miles to an answer

(Proclaimers, anyone)