# Travel.SE featured on StackExchange podcast

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

In [StackExchange podcast #**42**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/02/podcast-42-2/?cb=1), they talked about the graduation of Travel.SE. (The bit about Travel is around 36 minutes to 43 minutes.) Apparently, the graduation was held up because [Joel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/54/joel-spolsky) had strong opinions about [our original design](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/832/design-for-travel-stack-exchange).

There are a couple of other issues worth for the community to note:

- There is [a disproportionate number of highly active users](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all). By which I think it means we need to find ways to encourage a larger number of users to provide answers.
- There were questions raised about how welcoming the site is for travellers who aren't hardcore. (I'm rephrasing, but that was the gist of it.)

Any other things that the community wants to discuss related to the podcast?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, will have to listen to it later.

Comment: @MarkMayo: You are alluded to in the podcast but I am mentioned by name d-:

Comment: Alluded to?? Robbed :/

Comment: I think Joel(?) made some good points. A lot of the questions we have here seem targeted a lot towards hardcore travelers. That's not bad obviously, and it is clear we have a lot of such questions since a lot of the frequent users ARE hardcore travelers. However, we might look into how we can make this site also more welcoming for not so experienced travelers.

Comment: I've been listening to it. But now my ears hurt. Their accent is horrible and they made no effort to speak articulately. Are they assuming that their audience is made by by American English speakers?

Comment: And I have posted the following comment in the blog: "As a casual user of travel.stackexchange.com, I've been listening to this podcast with much interest. But now my ears hurt. The speakers' accent is horrible and they made no effort to speak articulately. Are they assuming that their audience is made by by American English speakers? This being said, and if I understood correctly, I share the speakers' point of view the hardcore questions asked and the welcome of newbies."

Comment: @MarcelC. - did you? I don't see any comment there? Unless I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: It has probably been censored. That's why I have also pasted it here

Comment: I for one welcome our inexperienced traveler overlords (-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing they did bring up was that we sort of have a new name "Travel Answers" - I'm still in favour of something less generic.

I encourage everyone to voice their opinion on [“Travel Answers” - to be, or not to be?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1158/101).