# HTML title is still "Travel Stack Exchange"

Tags: discussion, support, bug, status-bydesign, graduation

On the main site, the HTML title is still Travel Stack Exchange.

```
<title>Travel Stack Exchange</title>
```

Since it's graduated to its own site, shouldn't it be "Travel Answers"?

For the sake of comparison, [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com) has Seasoned Advice in its title:

```
<title>Seasoned Advice</title>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Anna Lear](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1690/anna-lear), The site name was suppose to be [changed back to **Travel Stack Exchange**](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1210/1712) and Travel Answers logo is to be changed. I guess they did the HTML part and forgot to update the logo.

Comment: @AnnaLear how's this going? :)